# What causes wifi network connections to timeout?

Tags: network, wifi, session-management

i was wondering what actually causes wifi network connections to timeout. for instance, say my laptop is connected to my wifi and i yank the battery out such that my laptop can't send any proper 802.11 deauthentication frames. at which point will my router release whatever resources it had reserved for my laptop? is it when my laptop's DHCP lease expires? or are there 802.11 frames that serve as a form of heartbeat? or is it something completely different?

thanks

Comment: I am not a guy to talk about this subject but as much as I know, it's not a standard... Each machine acts different... 

And mostly it is range oriented, not packet.
Moreover, sometimes to save battery, wifi is being shutdown by the client. (iPhones for example shut down wifi when screen light goes out)